# Search by FirstName OR LastName && FirstName AND LastName

Tags: c#, linq

We have an existing search tool that allows users to search a Lead table by address and contact name and phone number.  It was pointed out to us that it allows you to search by First Name OR Last Name, but not First Name AND Last Name.

So if there is a contact by the name of Dan Smith, a search for "Dan" will return the row, as will  search for "Smith", but a search for "Dan Smith" will not.

This is the original code:

```
var searchResults = from l in repo.GetAll()
    from lc in l.LeadContacts
    where
        statuses.Contains(l.LeadStatusID) && (
            l.Address != null && l.Address.Contains(Query) ||
            l.Address2 != null && l.Address2.Contains(Query) ||
            l.LotNumber != null && l.LotNumber.Contains(Query) ||
            l.City != null && l.City.Contains(Query) ||
            l.Zip != null && l.Zip.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.FirstName != null && lc.Contact.FirstName.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.LastName != null && lc.Contact.LastName.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.Phone != null && lc.Contact.Phone.Contains(Query)
        );
```

I thought this would work, but it throws an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
var searchResults = from l in repo.GetAll()
    from lc in l.LeadContacts
    let seller = lc.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + lc.Contact.LastName
    where
        statuses.Contains(l.LeadStatusID) && (
            l.Address != null && l.Address.Contains(Query) ||
            l.Address2 != null && l.Address2.Contains(Query) ||
            l.LotNumber != null && l.LotNumber.Contains(Query) ||
            l.City != null && l.City.Contains(Query) ||
            l.Zip != null && l.Zip.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.FirstName != null && lc.Contact.FirstName.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.LastName != null && lc.Contact.LastName.Contains(Query) ||
            seller != null && seller.Contains(Query) ||
            lc.Contact.Phone != null && lc.Contact.Phone.Contains(Query)
        );
```

Comment: `lc.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + lc.Contact.LastName` should be `lc.Contact.FirstName + " " + lc.Contact.LastName` - double quotes, not single.

Comment: awe gees.  Of course.

Comment: If you split Dan Smith into an array {"Dan", "Smith"} it is easier.